# How to remove certain html tags in php strings

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I was wondering how to remove all the tags from a HTML string but certain tags, such as `<p>`, `<b>` etc. I know I can do a function that searches for `<` symbol and the closest `>` and deletes it, but I was wondering if there is an already made command that does this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use php `strip_tags()` function to remove html tags from the string

Comment: You can try this regex `<(b|div|span)>(\S*)<\/(b|div|span)>` and use substitute `$2` to remove the tags. Tags you don't want are seperated by pipes (`|`), so you can use `preg_replace` - `$tags = "b|div|span";` and the regex would become `"<({$tags})>(\S*)<\/({$tags})>"`

Comment: @zDomi I wrote a function [here](https://pastebin.com/WqPk6xqk) that can do it for you. You supply the function with the string, and an array of tags you want to remove, and it returns the string without those elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove tags from a string in PHP (in this case, `$str = "<b>England</b> is lovely";`), you can use `strip_tags($str);` and it will return `England is lovely`
There is another parameter that you can add that doesn't remove certain tags, for example if `$str = "<b>England</b> is my <div>city</div>";` and you type `strip_tags($str, "<b>");`, you will get `<b>England</b> is my city`.
Hope I helped!